# Mathematica SVD recommendation system, assignment issue inside loop

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm translating the following [SVD recommendation system](http://www.igvita.com/2007/01/15/svd-recommendation-system-in-ruby/), written in ruby, to Mathematica:

```
require 'linalg'

users = { 1 => "Ben", 2 => "Tom", 3 => "John", 4 => "Fred" }
m = Linalg::DMatrix[
           #Ben, Tom, John, Fred
            [5,5,0,5], # season 1
            [5,0,3,4], # season 2
            [3,4,0,3], # season 3
            [0,0,5,3], # season 4
            [5,4,4,5], # season 5
            [5,4,5,5]  # season 6
            ]

# Compute the SVD Decomposition
u, s, vt = m.singular_value_decomposition
vt = vt.transpose

# Take the 2-rank approximation of the Matrix
#   - Take first and second columns of u  (6x2)
#   - Take first and second columns of vt (4x2)
#   - Take the first two eigen-values (2x2)
u2 = Linalg::DMatrix.join_columns [u.column(0), u.column(1)]
v2 = Linalg::DMatrix.join_columns [vt.column(0), vt.column(1)]
eig2 = Linalg::DMatrix.columns [s.column(0).to_a.flatten[0,2], s.column(1).to_a.flatten[0,2]]

# Here comes Bob, our new user
bob = Linalg::DMatrix[[5,5,0,0,0,5]]
bobEmbed = bob * u2 * eig2.inverse

# Compute the cosine similarity between Bob and every other User in our 2-D space
user_sim, count = {}, 1
v2.rows.each { |x|
    user_sim[count] = (bobEmbed.transpose.dot(x.transpose)) / (x.norm * bobEmbed.norm)
    count += 1
  }

# Remove all users who fall below the 0.90 cosine similarity cutoff and sort by similarity
similar_users = user_sim.delete_if {|k,sim| sim < 0.9 }.sort {|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1] }
similar_users.each { |u| printf "%s (ID: %d, Similarity: %0.3f) \\n", users[u[0]], u[0], u[1]  }

# We'll use a simple strategy in this case:
#   1) Select the most similar user
#   2) Compare all items rated by this user against your own and select items that you have not yet rated
#   3) Return the ratings for items I have not yet seen, but the most similar user has rated
similarUsersItems = m.column(similar_users[0][0]-1).transpose.to_a.flatten
myItems = bob.transpose.to_a.flatten

not_seen_yet = {}
myItems.each_index { |i|
  not_seen_yet[i+1] = similarUsersItems[i] if myItems[i] == 0 and similarUsersItems[i] != 0
}

printf "\\n %s recommends: \\n", users[similar_users[0][0]]
not_seen_yet.sort {|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1] }.each { |item|
  printf "\\tSeason %d .. I gave it a rating of %d \\n", item[0], item[1]
}

print "We've seen all the same seasons, bugger!" if not_seen_yet.size == 0
```

Here is the corresponding Mathematica code:

```
Clear[s, u, v, s2, u2, v2, m, n, testdata, trainingdata, user, user2d];
find1nn[trainingdata_, user_] := {
  {u , s, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[Transpose[trainingdata]];
  (* Reducr to 2 dimensions. *)
  u2 = u[[All, {1, 2}]];
  s2 = s[[{1, 2}, {1, 2}]];
  v2 = v[[All, {1, 2}]];
  user2d = user.u2.Inverse[s2];
  {m, n} = Dimensions[v2];
  closest = -1;
  index = -1;
  For[a = 1, a < m, a++,
    {distance = 1 - CosineDistance[v2[[a, {1, 2}]], user2d];,
        If[distance > closest, {closest = distance, index = a}];}];
  closestuserratings = trainingdata[[index]];
  closestuserratings
  }
rec[closest_, userx_] := {
  d = Dimensions[closest];
  For[b = 1, b <= d[[2]], b++,
    If[userx[[b]] == 0., userx[[b]] = closest[[1, b]]]
    ]
   userx
  }
finalrec[td_, user_] := rec[find1nn[td, user], user]
(*Clear[s,u,v,s2,u2,v2,m,n,testdata,trainingdata,user,user2d]*)
testdata = {{5., 5., 3., 0., 5., 5.}, {5., 0., 4., 1., 4., 4.}, {0., 
    3., 0., 5., 4., 5.}, {5., 4., 3., 3., 5., 5.}};
bob = {5., 0., 4., 0., 4., 5.};
(*recommend[testdata,bob]*)
find1nn[testdata, bob]
finalrec[testdata, bob]
```

**For some reason it doesn't assign the indices of the user inside the function, but does outside. What might be causing this to happen?**

Comment: Can you edit your question and just post the original snippet? If that link breaks, the _entire_ context of this question is lost.

Comment: I tired my own translation, but the signs I get for http://farm1.static.flickr.com/133/358494623_db22603640_o.png do not match.  What would cause this?

Comment: @Mr. An odd number of errors, adding up those coming from both parts.

Comment: I readily admit this math outside of my normal experience, but the SVD is being used as a proxy for Eigenvalues, and the Mathematica help on SVD mentions "The first two columns of v are the eigenvectors of Transpose[m].m up to sign:" so I think the flipped signs are expected, and presumably accounted for.

Answer (score 3):

Please look up variable localization tutorial in Mathematica documentation. The problem is in your rec function. The issue is that you can not normally modify input variables in Mathematica (you may be able to do it if your function has one of the Hold-attributes, so that the parameter in question is passed to it unevaluated, but this is not the case here):

```
rec[closest_, userxi_] := 
 Block[{d, b, userx = userxi}, {d = Dimensions[closest];
   For[b = 1, b <= d[[2]], b++, 
    If[userx[[b]] == 0., userx[[b]] = closest[[1, b]]]];
    userx}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to understand what you are trying to achieve, here you have a more Mathematca-ish, but equivalent (I hope) working code.

Explicit Loops are gone, and many unneeded vars eliminated.  All variables are now local, so no need to use Clear[ ].

```
find1nn[trainingdata_, user_] := 
  Module[{u, s, v, v2, user2d, m, distances}, 
   {u, s, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[Transpose[trainingdata]];
   v2 = v[[All, {1, 2}]];
   user2d = user.u[[All, {1, 2}]].Inverse[s[[{1, 2}, {1, 2}]]];
   m = First@Dimensions[v2];
   distances = (1 - CosineDistance[v2[[#, {1, 2}]], user2d]) & /@ Range[m - 1];
   {trainingdata[[Ordering[distances][[-1]]]]}];

rec[closest_, userxi_] := userxi[[#]] /. {0. -> closest[[1, #]]} & /@ 
                          Range[Dimensions[closest][[2]]];

finalrec[td_, user_] := rec[find1nn[td, user], user];
```

I am sure it can be optimized still a lot.

Comment: yep, Position[distances, #][[1, 1]] &@Max[distances] can be written as Ordering[distances][[-1]] which is more succinct and 30% faster.

Comment: @Sjoerd Good catch!  I was focusing on cleaning up some of the superfluous `Part` usages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my shot at this based on belisarius' code, and with Sjoerd's improvements.

```
find1nn[trainingdata_, user_] :=
  Module[{u, s, v, user2d, distances},
    {u, s, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[trainingdata\[Transpose], 2];
    user2d = user . u . Inverse@s;
    distances = # ~CosineDistance~ user2d & /@ Most@v;
    trainingdata[[ distances ~Ordering~ 1 ]]
  ]

rec[closest_, userxi_] := If[# == 0, #2, #] & ~MapThread~ {userxi, closest[[1]]}
```

Comment: +1 for Ordering[distances, -1] instead of Ordering[distances][[ -1]]. This is faster still.

Comment: Wizard Couldn't we just drop the 1- part of 1 - CosineDistance and test for the _smallest_ value (Ordering[distances, 1]) instead of the largest?

Comment: @Sjoerd, I don't know, I'll have to think about that.  But I have another concern: `Ordering` is only going to return one position, but `Position` could return multiple results.  Since I didn't bother to understand what this is doing, I don't know if that is a problem.  I need to look at the original code now.

Comment: Yeah, I have been thinking about that, but the original code just returns the index of the first occurrence of the maximum value, which seems to be just as arbitrary as picking the first/last result of Ordering or Position.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear[s, u, v, s2, u2, v2, m, n, testdata, trainingdata, user, user2d];
recommend[trainingdata_, user_] := {
  {u , s, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[Transpose[trainingdata]];
  (* Reducera till 2 dimensioner. *)
  u2 = u[[All, {1, 2}]];
  s2 = s[[{1, 2}, {1, 2}]];
  v2 = v[[All, {1, 2}]];
  user2d = user.u2.Inverse[s2];
  {m, n} = Dimensions[v2];
  closest = -1;
  index = -1;
  For[a = 1, a < m, a++,
    {distance = 1 - CosineDistance[v2[[a, {1, 2}]], user2d];,
        If[distance > closest, {closest = distance, index = a}];}];
  closestuserratings = trainingdata[[index]];
  d = Dimensions[closestuserratings];
  updateduser = Table[0, {i, 1, d[[1]]}];
  For[b = 1, b <= d[[1]], b++,
    If[user[[b]] == 0., updateduser[[b]] = closestuserratings[[b]], 
     updateduser[[b]] = user[[b]]]
    ]
   updateduser
  }
testdata = {{5., 5., 3., 0., 5., 5.}, {5., 0., 4., 1., 4., 4.}, {0., 
    3., 0., 5., 4., 5.}, {5., 4., 3., 3., 5., 5.}};
bob = {5., 0., 4., 0., 4., 5.};
recommend[testdata, bob]
```

{{5. Null, 0. Null, 4. Null, 1. Null, 4. Null, 5. Null}}

now it works but why the Nulls?

Comment: That's because your missing a ; after the For loop.  No offense meant, but have you seen the other contributions? The question has already been answered resulting in considerably improved code.